# Android Maps-API v2: where are the Overlays?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, overlay, google-maps-android-api-2

I have already written an app that uses GoogleMaps Api v1 in Android. This app uses several *Overlays* (or *ItemizedOverlays*) which handle a bunch of things autonomously (ie. lazy loading markers, as I have a whole lot of them and adding them all at once will force the app to close). I also use them as an interface for the user: He can decide which overlays (or which kind of markers from his perspective) he wants to see. I add or remove these *Overlays* accordingly. Now I want to switch to the new maps-v2-api. The documentation makes no mention of *Overlays*, and it seems that one cannot extend *Markers* as they are *final*.

Am I forced to kind of emulate the previous maps behavior, to be able to add and remove *Overlays* which handle *Markers* themself? Does anyone know a reason why Google removed this useful facility, and forces any developer to completely rewrite the GoogleMaps related code? I like to know also a reason for making the *Marker* class *final*, thus preventing anyone to add something related to it? (solutions I see store a global HashMap with the marker as key, and the infos they need as value, which is - in my point of view, very ugly considering that markers may have different models which are related to them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I forced to kind of emulate the previous maps behavior, to be able to add and remove Overlays which handle Markers themself?

Yes.

> Does anyone know a reason why Google removed this useful facility, and forces any dev to completely rewrite the GoogleMaps related code?

Google engineers probably know the reason.

All I know that, for simple scenarios, the new approach requires less code. Maps V1 requires overlays, and overlays are overkill for many apps.

> I like to know also a reason for making the Marker class final, thus preventing anyone to add something related to it?

Because the `Marker` is used for IPC and is not really retained within your process. Pretty much anything you do with Maps V2 results in IPC calls, based on [Cyril Mottier's research](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/12/07/the-google-maps-android-api-v2-utopia/).

Comment: Thanks for the mention of Cyril Mottier's research. I found his article very useful at http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=855